# What is causing my expected-unqualified id before '{' I only get it when I add the web code

Tags: button, web, arduino, ethernet, brackets

> the only portion that fails is the web block half way down.
>   exact syntax is sketch_feb26b.ino:652:1: error: expected unqualified-id before '{' token
>   I'm thinking too many brackets/wrong place?
>
> some of the memory calls have been omitted to save space
>
> the includes all work    #include

```
#include <Ethernet.h>
#include <avr/pgmspace.h>
#define DATA_1 (PORTC |=  0X01)    // DEFINE a value for DATA as 1  // for UNO
```

> the defines all work

```
#define DATA_0 (PORTC &=  0XFE)    // DEFINE a value for DATA 0   // for UNO
#define STRIP_PINOUT (DDRC=0x3F)  // DEFINE PORTC as OUTPUT // for UNO (change pins 0-5; leave PORTC 6 & 7 alone)
#define NOP "nop\n\t"
#define RED 0x0000ff
#define ORG 0x7700ee
#define YEL 0xff00ff
#define GRN 0xff0000
#define CYN 0x666600
#define BLU 0x00ff00
#define VIO 0x004040
#define MAG 0x00ffff
#define WHT 0xffffff
#define BLK 0x000000
#define R1  {RED,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK},
#define R2  {BLK,RED,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK},
#define R3  {BLK,BLK,RED,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK},
#define R4  {BLK,BLK,BLK,RED,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK},
#define R5  {BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,RED,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK},
#define R6  {BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,RED,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK},
#define R7  {BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,RED,BLK,BLK,BLK},
#define R8  {BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,RED,BLK,BLK},
#define R9  {BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,RED,BLK},
#define R10 {BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,RED},
#define RALL    R1 R2 R3 R4 R5 R6 R7 R8 R9 R10
#define G1  {GRN,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK},
#define G2  {BLK,GRN,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK},
#define G3  {BLK,BLK,GRN,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK},
#define G4  {BLK,BLK,BLK,GRN,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK},
#define G5  {BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,GRN,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK},
#define G6  {BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,GRN,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK},
#define G7  {BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,GRN,BLK,BLK,BLK},
#define G8  {BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,GRN,BLK,BLK},
#define G9  {BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,GRN,BLK},
#define G10 {BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,GRN},
#define GALL    G1 G2 G3 G4 G5 G6 G7 G8 G9 G10


\
PROGMEM const unsigned long chasing_RED[][10]={RALL}; 
PROGMEM const unsigned long chasing_GREEN[][10]={GALL};
PROGMEM const unsigned long knight_rider_red[38][10]={
  {RED,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK},
  {BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK},
  {BLK,RED,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK},
  {BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK},
  {BLK,BLK,RED,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK},
  {BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK},
  {BLK,BLK,BLK,RED,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK},
  {BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK},
  {BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,RED,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK},
  {BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK},
  {BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,RED,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK},
  {BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK},
  {BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,RED,BLK,BLK,BLK},
  {BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK},
  {BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,RED,BLK,BLK},
  {BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK},
  {BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,RED,BLK},
  {BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK},
  {BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,RED},
  {BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK},
  {BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,RED,BLK},
  {BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK},
  {BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,RED,BLK,BLK},
  {BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK},
  {BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,RED,BLK,BLK,BLK},
  {BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK},
  {BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,RED,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK},
  {BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK},
  {BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,RED,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK},
  {BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK},
  {BLK,BLK,BLK,RED,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK},
  {BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK},
  {BLK,BLK,RED,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK},
  {BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK},
  {BLK,RED,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK},
  {BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK},
  {RED,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK},
  {BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK},
};

PROGMEM const unsigned long knight_rider_green[38][10]={
  {GRN,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK},
  {BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK},
  {BLK,GRN,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK},
  {BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK},
  {BLK,BLK,GRN,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK},
  {BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK},
  {BLK,BLK,BLK,GRN,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK},
  {BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK},
  {BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,GRN,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK},
  {BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK},
  {BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,GRN,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK},
  {BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK},
  {BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,GRN,BLK,BLK,BLK},
  {BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK},
  {BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,GRN,BLK,BLK},
  {BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK},
  {BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,GRN,BLK},
  {BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK},
  {BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,GRN},
  {BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK},
  {BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,GRN,BLK},
  {BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK},
  {BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,GRN,BLK,BLK},
  {BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK},
  {BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,GRN,BLK,BLK,BLK},
  {BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK},
  {BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,GRN,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK},
  {BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK},
  {BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,GRN,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK},
  {BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK},
  {BLK,BLK,BLK,GRN,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK},
  {BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK},
  {BLK,BLK,GRN,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK},
  {BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK},
  {BLK,GRN,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK},
  {BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK},
  {GRN,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK},
  {BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK},
};

  PROGMEM const unsigned long chasing_green[][10]={
  {'GRN',BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK},
  {BLK,'GRN',BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK},
  {BLK,BLK,'GRN',BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK},
  {BLK,BLK,BLK,'GRN',BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK},
  {BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,'GRN',BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK},
  {BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,'GRN',BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK},
  {BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,'GRN',BLK,BLK,BLK},
  {BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,'GRN',BLK,BLK},
  {BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,'GRN',BLK},
  {BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,'GRN'},
};

PROGMEM const unsigned long chasing_BLUE[][10]={
  {'BLUE',BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK},
  {BLK,'BLUE',BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK},
  {BLK,BLK,'BLUE',BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK},
  {BLK,BLK,BLK,'BLUE',BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK},
  {BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,'BLUE',BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK},
  {BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,'BLUE',BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK},
  {BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,'BLUE',BLK,BLK,BLK},
  {BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,'BLUE',BLK,BLK},
  {BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,'BLUE',BLK},
  {BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,'BLUE'},
};

PROGMEM const unsigned long pattern_test_comet1[][10]={
  {0xfdfdfd,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK},
  {0x444444,0xfdfdfd,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK},
  {0x111111,0x444444,0xfdfdfd,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK},
  {BLK,0x111111,0x444444,0xfdfdfd,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK},
  {BLK,BLK,0x111111,0x444444,0xfdfdfd,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK},
  {BLK,BLK,BLK,0x111111,0x444444,0xfdfdfd,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK},
  {BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,0x111111,0x444444,0xfdfdfd,BLK,BLK,BLK},
  {BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,0x111111,0x444444,0xfdfdfd,BLK,BLK},
  {BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,0x111111,0x444444,0xfdfdfd,BLK},
  {BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,0x111111,0x444444,0xfdfdfd},
};

PROGMEM const unsigned long red_cylon_L[][10]={
  {BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,0x0000f0},
  {BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,0x0000f0,BLK},
  {BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,0x0000f0,BLK,BLK},
  {BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,0x0000f0,BLK,BLK,BLK},
  {BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,0x0000f0,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK},
  {BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,0x0000f0,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK},
  {BLK,BLK,BLK,0x0000f0,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK},
  {BLK,BLK,0x0000f0,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK},
  {BLK,0x0000f0,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK},
  {0x0000f0,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK},
};

PROGMEM const unsigned long star_trek_bridge[][10]={
  {0x0000f0,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,0x0000f0},
  {BLK,0x0000f0,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,0x0000f0,BLK},
  {BLK,BLK,0x0000f0,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,0x0000f0,BLK,BLK},
  {BLK,BLK,BLK,0x0000f0,BLK,BLK,0x0000f0,BLK,BLK,BLK},
  {BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,0x0000f0,0xf000f0,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK},
  {BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,0xd000d0,0xd000d0,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK},
  {BLK,BLK,BLK,0x0000f0,BLK,BLK,0x0000f0,BLK,BLK,BLK},
  {BLK,BLK,0x0000f0,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,0x0000f0,BLK,BLK},
  {BLK,0x0000f0,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,0x0000f0,BLK},
  {0x0000f0,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,BLK,0x0000f0},
};

const int arduinoPin2 = 2;
const int arduinoPin3 = 3;
const int arduinoPin4 = 4;
const int arduinoPin5 = 5;
const int arduinoPin6 = 6;
const int arduinoPin7 = 7;

void setup() {STRIP_PINOUT;

Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(arduinoPin2, INPUT);
  pinMode(arduinoPin3, INPUT);
  pinMode(arduinoPin4, INPUT);
  pinMode(arduinoPin5, INPUT);
  pinMode(arduinoPin6, INPUT);
  pinMode(arduinoPin7, INPUT);
  delay(1); reset_strip();  
}
```

> loop works fine with out web/ethernet portion

```
void loop(){

  if (digitalRead(8))
 {
client.print(” LED is <font color=’green’>ON</font>”);
}
else
{
client.print(” LED is <font color=’red’>OFF</font>”);
client.println(“<br />”);

}
```

> web button problem from here

```
client.print("<FORM action=\"http://192.168.2.118/\" >");
//client.print(“<FORM action=\"http://192.168.1.177/\” >”);
client.print(“<P> <INPUT type=\”radio\” name=\”status\” value=\”1\”>ON”);
client.print(“<P> <INPUT type=\”radio\” name=\”status\” value=\”0\”>OFF”);
client.print(“<P> <INPUT type=\”submit\” value=\”Submit\”> </FORM>”);
```

> web problem to here

```
break;
}


   send_1M_pattern(chasing_WHITE, 10, 35);  delay(1500);
  send_1M_pattern(chasing_WHITE, 10, 35);  delay(1500);
  send_1M_pattern(chasing_WHITE, 10, 20);  delay(300);
  send_1M_pattern(chasing_WHITE, 10, 20);  delay(300);
  send_1M_pattern(chasing_WHITE, 10, 15);  delay(20);
  send_1M_pattern(chasing_WHITE, 10, 20);  delay(20);
  send_1M_pattern(chasing_WHITE, 10, 15);  delay(50);
  send_1M_pattern(chasing_WHITE, 10, 25);  delay(50);
  send_1M_pattern(chasing_WHITE, 13, 25);  delay(50);
  send_1M_pattern(chasing_WHITE, 13, 25);  delay(50);
  send_1M_pattern(chasing_WHITE, 10, 20);  delay(20);
  send_1M_pattern(chasing_WHITE, 10, 20);  delay(20);
//
  send_1M_pattern(pattern_test_comet1, 10, 70);  delay(500);
  send_1M_pattern(pattern_test_comet2, 10, 70);  delay(500);
  send_1M_pattern(pattern_test_comet2, 10, 70);  delay(500);
  send_1M_pattern(pattern_test_comet2, 10, 70);  delay(500);
  send_1M_pattern(pattern_test_comet2, 10, 70);  delay(500);
  send_1M_pattern(pattern_test_comet2, 10, 70);  delay(500);
  send_1M_pattern(pattern_test_comet2, 10, 70);  delay(500);
  send_1M_pattern(pattern_test_comet2, 10, 70);  delay(500);
  send_1M_pattern(pattern_test_comet2, 10, 70);  delay(500);
  send_1M_pattern(pattern_test_comet2, 10, 70);  delay(500);
  send_1M_pattern(pattern_test_comet2, 10, 70);  delay(500);
  send_1M_pattern(pattern_test_comet3, 10, 70);  delay(500);
//
  send_1M_pattern(rainbow1, 10, 255);  delay(2000); 
  send_1M_pattern(rainbow1, 10, 10);   delay(1000);
  send_1M_pattern(rainbow1, 10, 10);   delay(1000);
  send_1M_pattern(rainbow1, 10, 10);   delay(1000);
  send_1M_pattern(rainbow1, 10, 255);  delay(1500); 
  send_1M_pattern(rainbow1, 10, 255);  delay(2000); 
  send_1M_pattern(rainbow1, 10, 255);  delay(2500); 
  send_1M_pattern(rainbow1, 10, 255);  delay(1000); 
  send_1M_pattern(rainbow1, 10, 255);  delay(1500); 
  send_1M_pattern(rainbow1, 10, 255);  delay(1000); 
  send_1M_pattern(rainbow1, 10, 255);  delay(1000); 
//
  send_1M_pattern(chasing_RED, 10, 30);       delay(25);
  send_1M_pattern(chasing_RED, 10, 30);       delay(25);
  send_1M_pattern(chasing_RED, 10, 30);       delay(25);
  send_1M_pattern(chasing_RED, 10, 30);       delay(25);
  send_1M_pattern(chasing_RED, 10, 30);       delay(25);
  send_1M_pattern(chasing_RED, 10, 30);       delay(25);
  send_1M_pattern(chasing_WHITE, 10, 30);     delay(25);
  send_1M_pattern(chasing_WHITE, 10, 30);     delay(25);
  send_1M_pattern(chasing_WHITE, 10, 30);     delay(25);
  send_1M_pattern(chasing_WHITE, 10, 30);     delay(25);
  send_1M_pattern(chasing_WHITE, 10, 30);     delay(25);
  send_1M_pattern(chasing_WHITE, 10, 30);     delay(25);
  send_1M_pattern(chasing_BLUE, 10, 30);     delay(25);
  send_1M_pattern(chasing_BLUE, 10, 30);     delay(25);
  send_1M_pattern(chasing_BLUE, 10, 30);     delay(25);
  send_1M_pattern(chasing_BLUE, 10, 30);     delay(25);
  send_1M_pattern(chasing_BLUE, 10, 30);     delay(25);
  send_1M_pattern(chasing_BLUE, 10, 30);     delay(25);
//
  send_1M_pattern(chasing_WHITE, 10, 20);     delay(25);
  send_1M_pattern(chasing_WHITE, 10, 20);     delay(25);
  send_1M_pattern(chasing_WHITE, 10, 20);     delay(25);
//

  send_1M_pattern(chasing_RED, 10, 30);         delay(5);
  send_1M_pattern(chasing_WHITE, 10, 30);       delay(5);
  send_1M_pattern(chasing_BLUE, 10, 30);        delay(5);
  send_1M_pattern(chasing_RED, 10, 30);         delay(5);
  send_1M_pattern(chasing_WHITE, 10, 30);       delay(5);
  send_1M_pattern(chasing_BLUE, 10, 30);        delay(5);
  send_1M_pattern(chasing_RED, 10, 30);         delay(5);
  send_1M_pattern(chasing_WHITE, 10, 30);       delay(5);
  send_1M_pattern(chasing_BLUE, 10, 30);        delay(5);
  send_1M_pattern(chasing_RED, 10, 30);         delay(5);
  send_1M_pattern(chasing_WHITE, 10, 30);       delay(5);
  send_1M_pattern(chasing_BLUE, 10, 30);        delay(5);
  send_1M_pattern(chasing_RED, 10, 30);         delay(5);
  send_1M_pattern(chasing_WHITE, 10, 30);       delay(5);
  send_1M_pattern(chasing_BLUE, 10, 30);        delay(5);
  send_1M_pattern(chasing_RED, 10, 30);         delay(5);
  send_1M_pattern(chasing_WHITE, 10, 30);       delay(5);
  send_1M_pattern(chasing_BLUE, 10, 30);        delay(5);
  send_1M_pattern(chasing_RED, 10, 30);         delay(5);
  send_1M_pattern(chasing_WHITE, 10, 30);       delay(5);
  send_1M_pattern(chasing_BLUE, 10, 30);        delay(5);
  send_1M_pattern(chasing_RED, 10, 30);         delay(5);
  send_1M_pattern(chasing_WHITE, 10, 30);       delay(5);
  send_1M_pattern(chasing_BLUE, 10, 30);        delay(5);
//
  send_1M_pattern(chasing_GREEN, 1, 500);    delay(500);
  send_1M_pattern(chasing_GREEN, 2, 500);    delay(500);
  send_1M_pattern(chasing_GREEN, 3, 500);    delay(500);
  send_1M_pattern(chasing_GREEN, 4, 500);    delay(500);
  send_1M_pattern(chasing_GREEN, 5, 500);    delay(500);
  send_1M_pattern(chasing_GREEN, 6, 500);    delay(500);
  send_1M_pattern(chasing_GREEN, 7, 500);    delay(500);
//
  send_1M_pattern(chasing_BLUE, 10, 500);     delay(500);
7  send_1M_pattern(star_trek_bridge, 10, 500);  delay(300);
  send_1M_pattern(rainbow1, 10, 100);         delay(100);
  send_1M_pattern(cylon_test_red, 100, 100); delay(900);
  send_1M_pattern(red_cylon_L, 10, 70);
  send_1M_pattern(red_white_blue, 10, 100);    delay(300);

 digitalWrite(arduinoPin2, LOW);
 digitalWrite(arduinoPin3, LOW);
 digitalWrite(arduinoPin4, LOW);
 digitalWrite(arduinoPin5, LOW);

 if (digitalRead(arduinoPin2) == HIGH)
{send_1M_pattern(chasing_RED, 10, 70);}

else

 if (digitalRead(arduinoPin3) == HIGH) 
{send_1M_pattern(chasing_GREEN, 10, 100);}
{send_1M_pattern(knight_rider_red, 38, 100);}
{send_1M_pattern(knight_rider_green, 38, 100);}//}  

void send_1M_pattern(const unsigned long data[][10], int pattern_no, int frame_rate)

{int i=0;
 int j=0;
 uint32_t temp_data;
 for (i=0;i<pattern_no;i++)
{
    noInterrupts(); // Turn OFF Interupts for more precise Pulse Timing using MCU processing cycles
    for (j=0;j<10;j++)
{
      temp_data=pgm_read_dword_near(&data[i][j]);
      send_strip(temp_data);
}
interrupts(); // Turn ON Interrupts after data is sent
delay(frame_rate); // ion of each FRAME, before the next series is sent;
}}
void send_strip(uint32_t data)
{int i;
 unsigned long j=0x800000;
 int d;
 for (i=0;i<24;i++)
{if (data & j)
{DATA_1; for (d=1;d<13;d++)
{__asm__(NOP);}
DATA_0; // Set OUTPUT PIN LOW ;
}
else
{DATA_1; for (d=1;d<5;d++)
{__asm__(NOP);}
DATA_0;
__asm__(NOP);
__asm__(NOP);
__asm__(NOP);}
j>>=1;
}} 
void reset_strip()    {DATA_0; delayMicroseconds(20);}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing unicode and ascii characters in your source.

> client.println(“...”);
>   client.print(“http://192.168.1.177/\” >”);
>   client.print(”color=’green’  ”);

You need to change the quotes to their ascii equivalent. The ones inside your strings need fixing too as your string is not a wide string: `L"A “wchar_t” string!";`, however wide strings aren't overly useful on an Arduino (API and libs only use ascii).